# CREATE TABLE on MySQL Master that does not replicate to the slaves

Tags: mysql, replication, create-table

I've got bit of script that creates a table on a MySQL master, fills it with data, does some work on the data and then drops the table again.

I don't want all this to be replicated to the slaves, as it is a waste of time. Is there any way to tell the slave to have nothing to do with this table, either by doing something clever in the CREATE TABLE statement itself or by setting a config command that states something like "Don't replicate any table beginning with 'temp_'" (the table name is dynamic to allow for multiple users, but it always starts with temp_).

Of course, using a proper temporary table would be perfect, but unfortunately I need to reference the table multiple times in one query, which MySQL doesn't allow.

Comment: you can do the same into slave instead on master (save some troubles)

Comment: Normally I would, but our SQL class sends all updates and inserts (etc) to the Master (as you'd imagine), and telling it to do otherwise would require quite a bit of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an [option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-ignore-table) for this,
but i not sure you will prefer this (require restart)

> Tells the slave SQL thread not to replicate any statement that updates the specified table, even if any other tables might be updated by the same statement. To specify more than one table to ignore, use this option multiple times, once for each table.

more [details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-rules.html)

Comment: That led me to replicate-wild-ignore-table, which allows wildcards, perfect. A restart isn't an issue as we're not live yet. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the table in another database.

And then do a statement like:

```
SELECT a.field1, b.field2 FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN db2.tablex b
.....
```

Comment: Hmm, that's a good idea. If there's not built-in way to do it that's probably what I'll go with.